# Ripple problem when using a type III Compensator for buck boost converter

Tags: high-voltage, gate-driving, buck-boost, ripple, bidirectional

I need your help, and from my last question here, I understand I need a closed-loop for my design, which helps to reduce the output overshooting. Below is the plot.

[image]

From the plot you can see my ripple is big at the outset and I am using this type III compensator, but I am really lost if I calculate the value correctly. Please note the block is a gate drive. This is only to give a picture of how the circuit I am designing will look. Also note, since this is a boost, the top left FET is always ''on'' and bottom right FET is switching at 500kHz.

[image]

I need your help how can I reduce the ripple at the output and calculate the right value for my compensator?

I have reposted it due to some text added in the schematic.

Comment: Please mark the nodes you are displaying graphically on your schematic.

Comment: Isn’t that your switching frequency? Can you zoom in more? Add output capacitance.

Answer (score 0):

Upper left FET is not "on,"  the gate voltage should be greater than the source.  Try putting 320 volts on the gate.[image]